# Multitenant configuration in efcore 2.2

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I use `EF Core 2.2` in a multi tenant application with one database. I used the following code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasQueryFilter(b => b.TenantId == _tenantId);
```

in `OnModelCreating` and it works but I would like to apply it to all of my models that have a `tenantId`. Please tell me if there is a way to implement this strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework Core 2.0 introduces global query filters that can be applied to entities when model is created. It makes it easier to build multi-tenant applications and support soft deleting of entities. use this link: [Global query filters in Entity Framework Core 2.0](https://gunnarpeipman.com/net/ef-core-global-query-filters/)
but you dont need caching in this sample.

Comment: Note that OnModelCreating is only called once per AppDomain per DbContext type, so the caching in the linked article is unnecessary.

Comment: @ David Browne Thanks for your attention, yes ofcourse I used it without caching, I forgot to explain it.